# How to use manual cache updates using RTK Query

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have recently started working on redux toolkit, Basically i want to refetch the data from database if there is mutation. I am using flatlist in my react native project where on pull to refresh i want my "getPosts" endpoint to refetch and get updated.

Note: I know about using tags for automated cache invalidation. but on web RTK query is not implemented.

Talking about pessimistic update:

```
 async onQueryStarted({ id, ...patch }, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
    try {
      const { data: updatedPost } = await queryF`enter code here`ulfilled
      const patchResult = dispatch(
        api.util.updateQueryData('getPost', id, (draft) => {
          Object.assign(draft, updatedPost)
        })
      )
    } catch {}
  },
```

just give a help how to call this function from APP.JS or anywhere from the app. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can just call `refetch`, you don't need anything that complicated. See the docs on [useQuery](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#usequery)

```
const myResult = useMyquery(args)

// in your pull to refresh trigger:
myResult.refetch()
```

If you are outside of a component, you can also still

```
store.dispatch(api.endpoints.myEndpoint.initiate(args, { track: false })))
```

to trigger a refetch

Comment: how to update a mutation cache from other mutation. I have a login mutation which added some data in cache, and I have other mutation to verify the email. What i want is when the email is verified, i want to update the login cache and set a key `verified` to `true` there.